# Issue adding a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to add a class when an input is checked. However, my attempt is not working. The class does not add. I tried `addClass` and `toggleClass`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
 $('.social-input').on('change', function () {
  var social1 = $('#social1');
  var social2 = $('#social2');
  if (social1.is(':checked')) {
   $(this).addClass('active');
  }
  else if (social2.is(':checked')) {
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   
  }
 });
```

```css
.social-option-box {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #45ba95;
 padding: 20px 0;
 margin: 20px 5%;
 width: 35%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45ba95;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.social-option-box.active {
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
 background: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
}
.social-option-box:hover {
 background-color: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.social-input {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social1">Yes, following
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social1" class="social-input" value="Yes, following">
</label>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social2">No, I'm not
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social2" class="social-input" value="Not following">
</label>
```

Comment: @empiric No, it doesn't. My class doesn't apply the css to the blocks. The background color/color stays the same.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle??

Comment: @Paul the code does exactly what it is supposed to do, inspect the elements in your browser console. You will see that the `active` class is added to the radio button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the other correct answers, you may be able to simplify this a little by doing the following JS.

```js
 $('.social-input').on('change', function () {
       var box = $('.social-option-box');
       var checkedBox = box.has('.social-input:checked');
       box.not(checkedBox).removeClass('active');
       checkedBox.addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
.social-option-box {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #45ba95;
 padding: 20px 0;
 margin: 20px 5%;
 width: 35%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45ba95;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.social-option-box.active {
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
 background: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
}
.social-option-box:hover {
 background-color: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.social-input {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social1">Yes, following
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social1" class="social-input" value="Yes, following">
</label>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social2">No, I'm not
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social2" class="social-input" value="Not following">
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The `$(this)` inside your event-handler refers to the `input` which invokes the event, so the class `active` will get added to the input and not the `label`.

When you change your code to match the closest `label` to the pressed input it will work:

```js
$('.social-input').on('change', function() {
  var social1 = $('#social1');
  var social2 = $('#social2');
  if (social1.is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('label').addClass('active');
  } else if (social2.is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.social-option-box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #45ba95;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 20px 5%;
  width: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #45ba95;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

.social-option-box.active {
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  background: #45ba95;
  color: #FFF;
}

.social-option-box:hover {
  background-color: #45ba95;
  color: #FFF;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

.social-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social1">Yes, following
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social1" class="social-input" value="Yes, following">
</label>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social2">No, I'm not
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social2" class="social-input" value="Not following">
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your input code is inside label element, I have used parent() to add toggleclass.

```js
$('.social-input').on('change', function () {
  var social1 = $('#social1');
  var social2 = $('#social2');
  if (social1.prop("checked") ) {
   social1.parent().addClass('active');
      social2.parent().removeClass('active');
  }
  else if (social2.prop("checked") ) {
   social2.parent().addClass('active');
      social1.parent().removeClass('active');   
  }
 });
```

```css
.social-option-box {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #45ba95;
 padding: 20px 0;
 margin: 20px 5%;
 width: 35%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 color: #45ba95;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.social-option-box.active {
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
 background: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
}
.social-option-box:hover {
 background-color: #45ba95;
 color: #FFF;
 transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
.social-input {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social1">Yes, following
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social1" class="social-input" value="Yes, following">
</label>
<label class="social-option-box" for="social2">No, I'm not
 <input type="radio" name="social" id="social2" class="social-input" value="Not following">
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. What is the advantage of changing `.is(":checked")` to `.prop("checked")`?

Comment: @Paul, without inspecting (again :D ) the jQuery source code I can guess, `.prop(":checked")` operates directly over the available HTMLElement ***properties*** therefore checking for the native `this.checked` - while doing `.is(":checked")` it might be first accessing the properties trough  the `.is` method - so one extra step, or two extra steps if you just used `social1[0].checked` or better by referencing an already cached vanilla JS DOM Element.

Comment: as far as I have undestood from jquery doc " the cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is to use the property" http://api.jquery.com/prop/